# How do I keep from calling default constructor in base class intializers?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, initialization, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to construct `Derived3` in such a way that the non-default constructors are called when `d2` is initialized. I would have expected that when `d2` was initialized, none of the default constructors would be called. With this code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base() : _message("Value initialized by default constructor")
    {
        std::cout << "Base default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    Base(std::string message) : _message(message)
    {
    }

    std::string     _message;
};

struct Derived1 : virtual public Base
{
    Derived1() : Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived1 default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    Derived1(std::string message) : Base(message)
    {   
    }

};

struct Derived2 : virtual public Base
{
    Derived2() : Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived2 default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    Derived2(std::string message) : Base(message)
    {
    }
};

struct Derived3 : virtual public Derived1, virtual public Derived2
{
    Derived3() : Derived1(), Derived2()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived3 default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    Derived3(std::string message) : Derived1(message), Derived2(message)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived3 d1 = Derived3();
    std::cout << d1._message << std::endl; // You get what you expect.

    Derived3 d2 = Derived3("Not initialized by default constructor");
    std::cout << d2._message << std::endl; // You get what you do not expect.
}
```

I would have expected that `d2._message` would be `"Not initialized by default constructor"`, when in actuality it is `"Value initialized by default constructor"`. Full output is:

```
Base default constructor called
Derived1 default constructor called
Derived2 default constructor called
Derived3 default constructor called
Value initialized by default constructor
Base default constructor called
Value initialized by default constructor
```

Expected Output:

```
Base default constructor called
Derived1 default constructor called
Derived2 default constructor called
Derived3 default constructor called
Value initialized by default constructor
Not initialized by default constructor
```

Why is this happening and how do I attain the expected behavior?

Comment: If you remove the default constructors, the compiler will likely error where they're used. Or you could add a breakpoint which might clue you in as well. Alternatively consider removing `Derived2` or `Derived1` to make more example smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you virtually inherit a base class, in all cases the virtually-inherited base class can be thought of as being always the immediate superclass of the so-called "most-derived" class. Change your `Derived3` constructor as follows:

```
Derived3(std::string message) : Derived1(message), Derived2(message),
                Base(message)
```

`Base` is really also the base class of your `Derived3`, because it gets virtually inherited from `Derived1` (and `Derived2`). That's what virtual inheritance is.

If you don't want `Base` to be default-constructed, you have to invoke the appropriate constructor yourself, here.

Even though you don't explicitly declare `Derived3` as inheriting from `Base`, it inherits it virtually, hence you can invoke its constructor from `Derived3`.

Note that if you declare `Derived4` as a subclass of `Derived3`, this constructor of `Base` here won't get called. `Derived4` will virtually inherit `Base`, and it will be responsible for constructing it.

What's really happening when you have virtually-inherited classes, is that ***every*** constructor you declare can be thought of as actually resulting in two actual constructors, in reality: a constructor that's responsible for constructing all virtually-inherited classes, and a constructor that does not. This `Derived3` constructor you declared above: you actually end up with two constructors from this. Two for the price of one: one that will construct `Base`, and one that will not. The one that will construct `Base` gets used when `Derived3` is constructed directly, and is the most-derived class. The second constructor is the same, except that it will not construct `Base`, and it gets used if a subclass of `Derived3` gets instantiated. You see it as one constructor, but the compiler does a lot more work, creates two of them, and makes sure that the right one gets used, when something needs to be constructed.